# pacman: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: undefined symbol: libssh2_session_set_read_timeout

Tags: curl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, arch, pacman-package-manager

I'm facing this issue in my wsl 2.0 Arch. After I update curl via pacman this error shows up.

```
pacman: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: undefined symbol: libssh2_session_set_read_timeout
```

Something similar was showing when try to use curl but i manage remove curl but error stayed.

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about **writing code**. Running programs other people wrote is out-of-scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TESTED SOLUTION]

I got the same problem and fixed it as the previous answer but i will explain it more:

1.Download the libssh2 from here:
https://archlinuxarm.org/packages/aarch64/libssh2

BE SURE TO CHANGE `aarch64` IN THE ABOVE URL TO YOUR CPU ARCH

2.unzip the zip you got from it and go to lib directory where you extracted the zip and move the `libssh2.so.1.0.1` to /usr/lib with root permissions

3.Test it and it will work!

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I think i had a corrupt file in `libssh2` on my Arch setup. Check with `md5sum -b /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1.0.1` and compare it to the release. I fixed it by replacing it manually.

If `sudo ldd -r /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1.0.1` should give an error at the bottom of the output it's most likely the same.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein linking back to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. System administration and troubleshooting (of tools that aren't exclusively for development purposes) is generally better suited to [unix.se] rather than here.